# Como se representa la clase Year

Tags: java, date

he visto que exite en java 8 clase Year pero como deberia implentar su valor?
si le doy 1903 me dice que es int no Year si lo pongo entre comillas me dice que es un String

```
public class Cuadros {
    private String titulo;
    private String autor;
    private String estilo;
    private int precio;
    private Year añoCreacion;

    public Cuadros(String titulo, String autor, String estilo, int precio, Year añoCreacion) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.estilo = estilo;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.añoCreacion = añoCreacion;
    }

    public Cuadros() {
    }
private ArrayList<Cuadros> datos = new ArrayList();
 datos.add(new Cuadros("La Mona Lisa", "Leonardo da Vinci", "Renacentista", 713000000, 1503));
        datos.add(new Cuadros("El grito", "Munch", "Expresionismo", 119900000, "1893)"));
        datos.add(new Cuadros("La persistencia de la memoria", "Dalí ", "Surrealismo", 400000000, "1931"));
        datos.add(new Cuadros("El nacimiento de Venus", "Sandro Botticelli", "Gotico", 10000000, "1482"));
        datos.add(new Cuadros("Guernica", "Pablo Picasso", "Cubismo", 300000000, "1937"));
        datos.add(new Cuadros("Los jugadores de cartas", "Paul Cézanne", "Posimpresionismo", 191000000, "1890"));
        this.adaptador = new AdaptadorCuadros(this, this.datos);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase `java.time.Year` puedes instanciarla así:

```
Year.of(2020);
```

o también:

```
Year.parse("2020");
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el entero que le pasas se interpreta así:

- El año 2 de la era actual ( o *después de Cristo*) se representa como 2.
- El año 1 de la era actual ( o *después de Cristo*) se representa como 1.
- El año 1 antes la era actual (o *antes de Cristo) se representa como 0.
- El año 2 antes la era actual (o *antes de Cristo) se representa como -1.

Por tanto puedes hacer algo como:

```
new Cuadros("El grito", "Munch", "Expresionismo", 119900000, Year.of(1893));
```

Y por supuesto esta clase implementa el método `toString()`, con lo que

```
System.out.print(Year.now());
```

Mostrará el año actual: `"2020"`

Comment: y como lo meto en el array?year of(2020)

Comment: Como lo paseo a String?